# how do I start a function at the end of an asynchronous function c# UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, text-to-speech

i have this simple code in c# UWP in which with the Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis class the app synthetize the first string, my problem is to synthetize the second string after that the first synthetize is finish. I know it's possible by make a only string that include str1+str2 but the scenario in which run this code is more complex and this it's not possible.(sorry for my low level of English)

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        string str1 = "weather data"; 
        talk(Textmeteo);
        string str2 = "hello world";
        talk(str2);
    }

    public async void talk(string text)
    {
        // The media object for controlling and playing audio.
        MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();

        // The object for controlling the speech synthesis engine (voice).
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        // Generate the audio stream from plain text.


        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await synth.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

        // Send the stream to the media object.
        mediaElement.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaElement.Play();

    }
```

Comment: why is `str1+str2` not possible in your scenario?

Comment: @AVK Because in first scenario while str1 is synthetized, a function run http request to read online the data which make up str2. In the second scenario i need of a data that you point to the end of first synthetize so i start the speech recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, it's a bad idea to have an `async` method return `void` instead of `Task` or `Task<T>`.
When you return a `Task`, you can simply add a continuation with [`ContinueWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    string str1 = "weather data"; 
    Task talkingTask = talk(Textmeteo);
    string str2 = "hello world";
    talkingTask = talkingTask.ContinueWith(completedTask => talk(str2));
}

public async Task talk(string text)
{
    // await...
}
```

Comment: excuse me how to use:  talkingTask = talkingTask.ContinueWith(completedTask => talk(str2));

Comment: @MilleHobby just like that. your `async talk` method returns a `Task` (this is done by the compiler), and `ContinueWith` tells it to start the next `Action` (the parameter) when the previous one has completed.

Comment: so if there are 10 strings, the `ContinueWith` should be repeated 10 Times?

Comment: @AVK yes, or one can do it like [polkduran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452904/5528593), which is effectively (quite) the same under the hood.

Comment: I highly doubt polkduran's answer works for this scenario. The answer although awaits the function but is not expecting any return values as Task so it will jump to next line for execution and will overlap to strings. Your answer should work.

Comment: the polkduran solution does not work because the async function start at the same time, i don't know why. in your solution @René Vogt i don't know how to declare talkingTask.

Comment: @AVK no, in polkduran's answer, the control flow is returned to the caller when the `await` is hit, and execution of his `MakeTalk` method is resumed when a  `talk` has completed. So it's indeed not the same as mine. My answer runs through the method while creating a sequence of tasks, continuing each other. His answer starts a talk and returns and comes back later to start the next talk. Depending on the `SynchronizationContext`, in his answer there maybe gaps between the talks.

Comment: @MilleHobby are you sure you changed the return type from `void` to `Task`? (I am talking about my answer).

Comment: @MilleHobby did you change `async void talk()` to `async Task talk()`? Then my code as it is shown should work (except for whatever `Textmeteo` is, copied that from you). But I'm afraid it sounds like you should at first read up on `async/await` and `Task` in c# to get a better understanding of what's happening. In polkduran's answer the tasks are also _not_ started at the same time.

Comment: the error of "textmeteo" is the simple copy error by my app. i change async void talk() to async Task talk() but in pubblic MainPage talkingTask = talkingTask.ContinueWith(completedTask => talk(str2)); take me an error because talkingTask variable isnot declare, how to declare talkingTask?

Comment: @MilleHobby Please _read_ the answer. Ì declared `talkingTask` two lines before with the return value of your first `talk` call: `Task talkingTask = talk(str1);`.

Comment: @René Vogt excuse me, for error I commented this line, but now syntetize ony the first string. I must add a return in public async Task talk() ?

Comment: @MilleHobby no need for a return, the compiler converts the `async` method into a state machine that returns a `Task` already. _Why_ the second string is not executed I can't tell from here. You may debug or add a `talkingTask.Wait()` at the end to see if you get any exception.

Comment: i try to make the debug and the synthesis of first string begin after the line in which there is talkingTask = talkingTask.ContinueWith(completedTask => talk(str2)); , this is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Make the method `talk` return a `Task` and not `void`.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    MakeTalk();
}

private async void MakeTalk()
{
    // Surround by a try catch as we have async void.
    string str1 = "weather data"; 
    await talk(Textmeteo);
    string str2 = "hello world";
    await talk(str2);
}

public async Task talk(string text)
{
   // [...]
}
```